# How to stop d3.histogram() trimming leading and trailing empty bins

Tags: d3.js, histogram

I am using `d3.histogram().thresholds(myThresholds)(myDates)` to bin myDates by month.

myDates is an array of unix timestamps (e.g. June 8, 2020 8:28:18 PM GMT is 1591648098000 ms since the Unix epoch).

I have created an array of myThresholds[] covering all the months for all the years associated with myDates (e.g. if myDates contains times for Apr, 2013 and Jan, 2015, the thresholds will contain unix timestamps marking the begin and end times for all months in 2013, 2014 and 2015). Note that I am **deliberately** creating bins prior to Apr, 2013 and after Jan, 2015 even though I know in advance that they will end up empty. This is because I want to display histogram data for entire years.

The end result is that d3.histogram() will create the bins and fill them in with the desired information but throws away any leading empty bins and trailing empty bins. If there are empty bins in the middle of the histogram data, they are kept.

How do I stop it from throwing away the leading and trailing empty bins?

Answer (score 1):

Was about to submit the question when I realized that possibly explicitly specifying the domain would help. It did...

So, now the code is `d3.histogram().domain(myDomain).thresholds(myThresholds)(myData)`